# Trouble with Teamviewer, X and Window manager on headless server

Tags: linux, xorg, xinit, teamviewer

What I need to achieve is this:

1. Run Teamviewer host on Ubuntu headless server CLI
2. Increase the resolution to something workable
3. Open a browser on the server through TV without installing a complete desktop enviroment.

1) I got working but the problem is the resolution is only 640x480 when no monitor is connected.

2) I got working as well (when connected to a monitor) but it breaks Teamviewer.

To increase the resolution I tried things such as adding a line to Grub or install the dummby xorg driver and use a dummby config. This all breaks Teamviewer. Basically on a out of the box 18.04 server install as soon as you install something like xinit or whatever Teamviewer will just not work anymore. I think this is because after installing the above it is not detecting a monitor anymore because as soon as I connect a monitor I Teamviewer starts working again.

Also all commands I can find such as xrandr always say unable to open monitor, even with a real monitor connected.

Answer (score 0):

If no monitor is connected use `Xvfb` which does not require any physical display or I/O devices.

When I don't want a "full desktop environment" I use `blackbox` or `twm`.  twm is smaller but blackbox is more modern

I can't say what steps are required to launch teamviewer, have you tried `xvnc` instead? (tunneled over ssh, not exposed to the internet)

on onse server I use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#vfbx

export DISPLAY=:2
Xvfb $DISPLAY -screen 0 1286x1024x24 &
sleep 1
x11vnc --connect 127.0.0.1$DISPLAY &
firefox-esr --no-remote &
blackbox
```

I lauch it like:

```
vncviewer  -listen 2 -encodings tight -quality 0 &
ssh user@host -R 5502:127.0.0.1:5502 ./vfbx
```